# Cells text always getting empty string("") in Gridview rowdatabound

Tags: asp.net

I'm trying to do the disable the delete button for the admin role in the list of users which I had bound in gridview.

So, I went with `rowdatabound` option where I can disable based on the condition as like checking the text of the role column.

If the role columns text is "Admin" then I had to disable the "Delete" button which I had customized.

Unfortunately I'm not able to get the text of the cells while fetching the data.
I had used the statement as like below :

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        Button btn = (e.Row.FindControl("Delbutton") as Button);

        if(e.Row.Cells[7].Text == "ADMIN")
        {
            btn.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
}
```

My aspx page :

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"  
       AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
       OnPageIndexChanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging" 
       PagerSettings-Mode="Numeric" 
       PagerSettings-PreviousPageText="Previous"
        PagerSettings-PageButtonCount="15" 
       PagerSettings-NextPageText="Next" 
       PagerStyle-ForeColor="WhiteSmoke" 
       OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound">
       <Columns>
           <asp:TemplateField>
               <ItemTemplate>
                   <asp:button ID="button1" runat="server" Text="Select" OnClick="button1_Click"  ></asp:button>
               </ItemTemplate>
           </asp:TemplateField>
           <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID">
               <ItemTemplate>
                   <asp:Label ID="id" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("ID") %>'></asp:Label>
               </ItemTemplate>
           </asp:TemplateField>
           <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Email">
               <ItemTemplate>
                  <asp:Label ID="idemail" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Email") %>'></asp:Label>
               </ItemTemplate>
           </asp:TemplateField>
           <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
               <ItemTemplate>
                  <asp:Label ID="idName" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Name") %>'></asp:Label>
               </ItemTemplate>
           </asp:TemplateField>
           <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Passwor">
               <ItemTemplate>
                  <asp:Label ID="idPassword" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Passwor") %>'></asp:Label>
               </ItemTemplate>
           </asp:TemplateField>
           <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="MobileNumber">
               <ItemTemplate>
                  <asp:Label ID="idMobileNumber" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("MobileNumber") %>'></asp:Label>
               </ItemTemplate>
           </asp:TemplateField>
           <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Gender">
               <ItemTemplate>
                  <asp:Label ID="idGender" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Gender") %>'></asp:Label>
               </ItemTemplate>
           </asp:TemplateField>
           <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Qulification">
               <ItemTemplate>
                  <asp:Label ID="idQulification" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Qulification") %>'></asp:Label>
               </ItemTemplate>
               </asp:TemplateField>
               <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Role">
               <ItemTemplate>
                  <asp:Label ID="idRole" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Role") %>'></asp:Label>
               </ItemTemplate>
           </asp:TemplateField>
           <asp:TemplateField>
               <ItemTemplate>
                   <asp:button ID="Delbutton" runat="server" Text="Delete" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure, Do you want to delete.')" OnClick="Delbutton_Click" ></asp:button>
               </ItemTemplate>
           </asp:TemplateField>
       </Columns>
        <PagerSettings NextPageText="Next" PageButtonCount="15" PreviousPageText="Previous"></PagerSettings>
    </asp:GridView>
```

[Please check the image of my code on debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MsKYM.png)

[This was my data on page after loaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CyHSV.png)

Comment: Fetch your label the same way you fetch `btn`, and reference its text, rather than the cell text.

Comment: @Santi Thnaks, It worked.